# Is it possible to use google datastore without app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a "disable app engine only" button so I don't have a rogue hello world application hanging around on the web?

When I use this button it disables everything including datastore which I use separately as my haskell app database.

[image: app engine]

Comment: Have you tried deploying with an app.yaml with no handlers defined.

Comment: I just tried but I get a error message "No URLMap entries found in application configuration"

Comment: you can deploy a python app with just a static handler (static dir) with nothing in it.  However then you <myapp>.appengine.com will just give 404's.  YOu can't stop the app trying to serve.  What do you want it to do?

Comment: stop it from wasting resources :) anyway I think datastore should be more separated from app engine. I will just stick with my hello world app, thanks.

Comment: why not use cloud datastore - just set up a new account then you don't have any app at all.

Comment: Hmm that would work, but I still find it silly there is no other way and I have to ship all my data to the other account.

Comment: I suppose you're using your app as some kind of end-point API, so you just need to remove your main handler and just leave the api one (and remove also your "rogue helloworld")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you [cannot disable your App Engine and still have Datastore working](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#dependency_on_gae_name_short_application).

That being said, you only need App Engine enabled, you don't need to have a functioning app or even a deployed app.